# What is the correct way to compare datetimes with dask?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, dask

Dask can't compare datetimes values in contrast to pandas:

```py
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

start = datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1)
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'a':range(0,10)})
df['time_key'] = pd.date_range(start, periods=10, freq="M")
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=3)

df.time_key.dt.date < datetime.date(2011, 3, 1) # works
ddf.time_key.dt.date < datetime.date(2011, 3, 1) # doesn't work
```

Error:

```
ValueError: Metadata inference failed in `lt`.

Original error is below:
------------------------
TypeError("'<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.date'")
```

But when I try to convert `str` to `datetime`:

```py
ddf.time_key.dt.date.apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d"))
```

I get the error
`ValueError("time data 'foo' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'")`

What is the correct way to compare datetimes with dask?

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am facing a similar issue!